If $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ converges for some sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$
I got stuck on the following problem:

Suppose $f$ is continuous and non-negative on $[1 ,\infty)$
and that $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$ converges. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with
$x_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ converges.

I tried to set $x_n=n$ and divide the integral to $n$ parts on size $1$ (the intervals $[n,n+1]$) so that
$$\int_{1}^\infty f(x) \, \mathrm dx = \int_{1}^{2} f(x) \, \mathrm dx + \int_{2}^{3} f(x) \, \mathrm dx + \int_{3}^{4} f(x) \, \mathrm dx + \dots + \int_{n-1}^{n} f(x) \, \mathrm dx $$
and it simplified to $F(n)-F(1)$. Does anyone have an idea on how to continue?

For $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, let $x_n\in[n,n+1]$ be such that
$$f(x_n)=\min_{x\in[n,n+1]}f(x),$$
which exists as $f$ is continuous. Clearly $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ as $x_n\geq n$ for all $n\in\mathbb Z^+$. Then
$$\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\,\mathrm dx\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_n^{n+1}f(x_n)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n).$$
As the left-hand side is finite, and $f$ is non-negative, it follows that the series above is finite (and so converges).

appreciate your answer mate!

(+1) Here's how I understand the philosophy behind this answer: $f$ is not monotone decreasing so you force it to become what it is not and then apply Integral test :)

@Nothingspecial that's pretty much what I was thinking when I wrote the answer :)

Here's another way to do this. The mean value theorem for integrals gives
$$\int_a^b f(t) dt = (b-a) f(c),$$
where $c \in (a,b)$.  In particular,
$$\int_1^n f(t) dt = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} f(t) dt = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} f(c_k),$$
where $c_k \in (k,k+1)$. Therefore
$$\int_1^\infty f(t) dt = \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_1^n f(t) dt =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty f(c_k).$$
So not only the series converges, it converges to the integral.

That's same answer as mine... I was just 8 minutes faster :)

@Nothingspecial Your solution used — unnecessarily — a more general and (arguably) more subtle result.

Recall the First mean value theorem of integral calculus (or at least that's what my reference book calls it.):

If 

$f,g\colon\,[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be two integrable functions 
$g(x)$ has the same sign for all $x\in[a,b]$

then there is is a number $\mu$: $\inf\limits_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)\leq \mu\leq \sup\limits_{x\in [a,b]} f(x)\tag*{}$ such that $$\int_a^b f(x)\,g(x)\,\mathrm dx = \mu \int_a^b g(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$
In particular, if $f$ is continuous then $\mu = f(\xi)$ for some $\xi\in [a,b]$.

If you take $g(x)=1$ for all $x$ then for each $n\in\mathbb Z^+$, $\exists\, x_n\in [n,n+1]$ s.t.
$$\int_n^{n+1} f(x)\mathrm dx = f(x_n)\int_n^{n+1}\mathrm dx = f(x_n)$$
You don't need $f$ to be non-negative. Let me change the problem a bit and make it more general.

Suppose $f$ is continuous on $[1 ,\infty)$
and that $\int_{1}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm dx$ converges. Then there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ with
$x_n \to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)$ converges and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(x_n)=\int_1^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx.$$

Now,
$$\begin{align}\int_1^\infty f(x)\mathrm dx &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\mathrm dx\\ &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f(x_n)\quad  \blacksquare\end{align}$$
Of course, you wouldn't forget to check that $x_n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.
